# Sync music from iPod classic to iTunes?

Tags: data-synchronization, music, data-transfer, ipod-classic

My Father's iPod (classic) has all of his music arranged and named perfectly.

However, his iTunes is not in sync with his iPod, as his computer hard drive was damaged, and all of his iTunes data lost. Because of this, we have not been able to back up the iPod, and if it is damaged, he will have to rename thousands of songs again.

Is there a way to sync the music from his iPod **to** his iTunes, or any other possible way to backup the iPod data?

Comment: Did you try following steps? open iTunes, press cmd+o (Files -> Add to Library), navigate to your iPod device as an external drive, select folder with music files (they will be named randomly,  but all songs naming data is stored inside files so it will be recovered by iTunes) and see them added to iTunes library. Then, if you have advanced preference option "Keep iTunes media organized" turned off - select all newly added files and pick menu option "Consolidate files".

Comment: Just to make sure you get the best answer possible, you should probably [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/288772/edit) your question to clarify the version of iTunes you're running and whether it's on a PC or Mac?

Answer (score 9):

Not officially.  Syncing is intended to go in one direction:  from iTunes to iPod.

That said, there are some third-party apps that will permit this.

https://tunesgo.wondershare.com/music-transfer/transfer-music-from-ipod-touch-to-computer.html

Good discussion on Apple Support:
https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3991

Answer (score 8):

iMazing has worked really well for me.

https://imazing.com/transfer-all-data-to-any-other-iphone-or-ipad

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the software you recommended is better than others out there.  Answers should be self-contained and include all relevant info to address the concerns in the question.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Answer (score 7):

To add files from iPod classic back to iTunes, go through following steps:

1. Connect your iPod to Mac (or PC) and Open iTunes.
2. Pick menu "File -> Add to Library..." (or press cmd+o).
3. In Open dialogue, navigate to your iPod Classic. It should be displayed as an external drive.
4. Select folder **iPod_Control/Music** and click "Open" button. Note, iPhod_Control folder may be hidden, so turn on showing hidden files on Windows, or use cmd+shift+g combination to open "Go to Folder" input box and just type the name of needed folder (in your case iPod_Control).
5. See new files added to your iTunes library. Now, if you have option "Advanced Preferences -> Keep iTunes Media folder organized" turned off - select all newly added files and pick menu "File -> Library -> Consolidate files" for them

All track info is storing inside of music file, so don't care about random names - iTunes will recover track info while opening.

Also, you may want to know about encrypted music files. Tracks that was bought on iTunes and added to iPod will not be recovered in such way - use you Apple ID to get access to them.